# print business reports from database data

Tags: php, mysql

I am learning php and in doing it I had a problem.

I have to insert in a table of the payment data taken from a second table but only after checking that the id of the person corresponds to the id of the person who made the payment.

```
<?php

3 Query ...


while($rowSocio = mysqli_fetch_array($mostraSocio)) {
    $idSocio = $rowSocio['socio_id'];
    $nomeSocio = $rowSocio['socio_nome'];
    $cognomeSocio = $rowSocio['socio_cognome'];

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>{$cognomeSocio}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$nomeSocio}</td>";

    $i = 0;
    $print = "0";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($mostraOperazione)) {

        $id = $row['socio_id'];
        $nome = $row['socio_nome'];
        $cognome = $row['socio_cognome'];
        $importo = $row['opfin_importo'];
        $quota = $row['quota_nome'];


        if($idSocio === $id) {

            if($quota === "Prima Rata" && $print !== "1") {
                echo "<td class='align-rx'>€ {$importo}</td>";
                echo "<td></td>";
                echo "<td></td>";
                echo "<td></td>";
                $i++;
                $print = "1";

            } elseif($quota === "Seconda Rata" && $print !== "2") {
                echo "<td></td>";
                echo "<td class='align-rx'>€ {$importo}</td>";
                echo "<td></td>";
                echo "<td></td>";
                $i++;
                $print = "2";

            } elseif($quota === "Terza Rata" && $print !== "3") {
                echo "<td></td>";
                echo "<td></td>";
                echo "<td class='align-rx'>€ {$importo}</td>";
                echo "<td></td>";
                $i++;
                $print = "3";

            } elseif($quota === "Quota Stagionale" && $print !== "4") {
                echo "<td></td>";
                echo "<td></td>";
                echo "<td></td>";
                $i++;
                $print = "4";

                echo "<td class='align-rx'>€ {$importo}</td>";
            } else {
                echo "<td></td>";
                echo "<td></td>";
                echo "<td></td>";
                echo "<td></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                $i++;

            }
        } else {
            echo "</tr>";
            $i++;
        }


    }
}
?>
```

so I only print the names of the people and not the payments they make

output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSwo6.png)

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is largely an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: It looks like you're doing filtering in the application, as in `SELECT * FROM x` and then testing for a particular ID value. Use `SELECT ... WHERE id=?` to grab only what you need.

Comment: now there are 150 names in the db, in order not to repeat the query for each person I wanted to run it once and then cycle through the right combination

Comment: It's really hard to follow what's going on here since this is a mess of PHP, HTML, and a bunch of other logic. You've got a loop inside a loop, which is adding to the confusion. Normally if you want to avoid lookups you create a lookup table (e.g. associative array) so you can quickly fetch whatever data you need for a particular record, like `$socio[$id]`. This is a constant time (e.g. *O(n)*) lookup, unlike this double-loop which is *O(n^2)*, or geometric.

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavors from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I try to apply to learn better what I read in the manual.
you are right in saying that this is a code mess. O.o

Comment: Just looking out for you here, as once code gets this complicated and tangled solving problems becomes a lot more work. The manual is important, but don't forget overall strategy (e.g. code organization, file structure, use of templates vs. inline code) will pay much bigger dividends.

Comment: You should strive get all your data, then switch to html using php only for looping, data substitution, and *minimal* conditional testing.  As mentioned above, you’re doing too much computing and data manipulation when printing your output. It looks far too clever, when what you want is to be able to glance at it and say, “I get it.”

Comment: in the db there are three tables: people, operation and "odds". in the report I must have a table with two columns for people's first and last name, and the columns for the "odds". Inside I have to enter the data collected in the operation table after making comparisons. I try to insert a photo of the output

Comment: @tadman said it well while I was typing... slowly... separate code from presentation.

Comment: thanks Tadman & Tim Morton for the valuable advice.